# "I intended him to come" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I intended him to come.

What is a meaning and context of using *intend* there?
It may be known from dictionaries that *intend* means **to have as a plan or purpose**. Well let we make this substitute:

> I had as a plan that he must come.

Is the sense of the sentence kept on?

Doesn't it sound awkward? How to implement a proper substitute of meaning of *intend* to expose it?

Comment: *I intended him to come* isn't a particularly common turn of phrase, but if it *did* occur it would most likely mean *It **had been / was my intention** that he should come* (usually, with the implication *BUT my intention was thwarted; he **didn't** come*). To ***intend*** something to happen isn't quite the same as ***wanting, planning for,*** or ***expecting*** it to happen, because it implies actively doing things to achieve the intended outcome (***planning for*** an outcome doesn't imply doing anything to encourage it; it just means being ***ready, prepared*** for it *if it happens*).

Comment: *I had as a plan that he must come* = *The purpose of my plan was to ensure that he came*. But *I planned on him coming* and *I planned for him to come* both mean *The purpose of my plan was to ensure that **if he came** [which I expected to happen] this wouldn't be disruptive; his presence was **anticipated**, rather than **sought.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substitution adds elements that are not in the original. A better "substitution" would be

> I had planned for him to come.

Alternatively,

> I wanted him to come

could also express a different usage of intended (though, "intended" implies more certainty than "wanted" does; "wanted" merely expresses desire, whereas "intended" expresses desire combined with planning, or at least expectation).

As a side note,

> I intended *for* him to come/I wanted him to come/I expected him to come

all sound more natural to me as a native (American) English speaker; the above doesn't sound *wrong*, but rather archaic and old-fashioned. The phrasing would make me think of an elderly person, or dialog in a narrative set far in the past.

Comment: Many thanks for such a wonderful answer. Especialy for "for-exmple". I am only begginer but it seems to me that "for" is more logically there.